# Ace Code Editor auto completion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ace-editor

I have a textarea that is turned into an ace code editor in browser.  Basically it just mimics the textarea to a div then gets the value on submit.

Auto completion doesn't work.  This is my script:

```
$(function () {
  $('textarea[data-editor]').each(function () {
    var textarea = $(this);
    var mode = textarea.data('editor');
    var editDiv = $('<div>', {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: textarea.height(),
      'class': textarea.attr('class')
    }).insertBefore(textarea);
    textarea.css('display', 'none');
    var editor = ace.edit(editDiv[0]);        
    editor.getSession().setValue(textarea.val());
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + mode);
    // enable autocompletion and snippets
    ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    editor.setOptions({
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableEmmet: true
    });
        // editor.setTheme("ace/theme/idle_fingers");
        editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
        editor.session.setFoldStyle('manual');
        editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
        // copy back to textarea on form submit...
        textarea.closest('form').submit(function () {
          textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
        })
      });
});
```

If i remove everything inside `$('textarea[data-editor]').each(function () {` and just run

```
ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    editor.setOptions({
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableEmmet: true
    });
```

it works fine.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are setting wrong mode that doesn't have any completions.
The version bellow works

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea[data-editor]').each(function() {
    var textarea = $(this);
    var mode = textarea.data('editor');
    var editDiv = $('<div>', {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: textarea.height(),
      'class': textarea.attr('class')
    }).insertBefore(textarea);
    textarea.css('display', 'none');
    var editor = ace.edit(editDiv[0]);
    editor.session.setValue(textarea.val());
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/" + mode);
    
    // enable autocompletion and snippets
    ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    editor.setOptions({
      enableSnippets: true,
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
      enableEmmet: true,
      useWorker: false,
      theme: "ace/theme/idle_fingers",
      showPrintMargin: false,
      showFoldWidgets: false
    });
    // copy back to textarea on form submit...
    textarea.closest('form').submit(function() {
      textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ext-emmet.js"></script>


<form>
  <textarea data-editor='javascript' rows="10">{
}</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```